# Paypal BN (Build Notation) - How to get it from Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart

**Reason:** I need to write my own Paypal cart (long story) for existing web site.
The main reason for this is to use coupons (gift coupons and discount coupons).

I have found a fantastic tutorial here (probable the best one out there)
https://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php

I got everything to work, including submitting UNENCRYPTED purchases to Paypal.

But everything fails on the BN (Build Notation) you NEED it to submit an encrypted transaction to Paypal.
Specific line:
$hash['bn']= 'StellarWebSolutions.PHP_EWP2'; 
(This one is for the sample code developer)

Every time (I have tried 3 times) contacting PayPal - They seem to have no idea. This is consistent with googling PayPal information.

The closest I got, was contacting 
"PayPal Merchant Solutions" in the US.
They have taken my "Developer Survey" for approval - and I have not heard anything since.

Can ANYONE advise me please, how to obtain BN code from PayPal?

I can't be the only developer in the world who needs it.

**Any guidance deeply appreciated.**

Comment: No response from PayPal so far.